# Disable or mocking OAuth2 for integration test in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, integration-testing, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to disable/mock a local OAuth2 server while running an integration test, but so far most ways of doing so involve Spring MVC, which I'm not using. This is the most common solution:

```
 this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
```

On Spring Boot, I have a `TestRestTemplate` for requests on the endpoints. I have this on the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = {"eureka.client.enabled:false"})
public class ApiControllerTest {



 @Test
    @WithOauth2TestAuthentication
public void employeesPost() throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer FOO");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

    ResponseEntity<OperationResultDTO> responseEntity =
            this.restTemplate.postForEntity("/employees", new HttpEntity<>(loggedEmployee, headers), OperationResultDTO.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
}
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithOAuth2AuthenticationSecurityContextFactory.class)
public @interface WithOauth2TestAuthentication {
    String clientId() default "temporal";

    String username() default "username";

    String[] scopes() default { "read", "write", "trust" };
}
```

SecurityContextFactory:

```
public class WithOAuth2AuthenticationSecurityContextFactory
    implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithOauth2TestAuthentication> {
@Override
public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithOauth2TestAuthentication annotation) {
    Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(scopes, annotation.scopes());

    OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request(null, annotation.clientId(),
            null, true, scopes, null, null,
            null, null);
    Authentication auth2Authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Request,
            new TestingAuthenticationToken(annotation.username(), null, "read"));

    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    context.setAuthentication(auth2Authentication);
    return context;
}
}
```

So far, every test run has thrown me an assertion error, meaning that the request returned 401 instead of 422 which is what I'm aiming for. I've tried faking the OAuth server with these instructions: http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/faking_oauth_sso/ to no avail (I'm also trying to avoid it, but my shot had no success). I would also be okay with mocking an authorization token, but I'm not sure how to do that here.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was putting the OAuth2 configuration file on a different `@Profile`, and creating an abstract class for each controller test, and *also* using MockMvc with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({ "default", "local", "test" })
abstract class BaseControllerTest {
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SampleControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
// ...

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void aTest() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result =
            mockMvc.perform(get(URL_TEMPLATE).with(csrf()))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
    }
}
```

With that setup, the `SecurityContext` does return a mock user, which was ultimately what was causing my requests to fail with the 401 HTTP code. If I need to aim for an Unprocessable Entity response, just switch `status().isOk()` with `status().isUnprocessableEntity()`.